# SimpleHTTPRequestHandler Override do_GET

Tags: python

I want to extend SimpleHTTPRequestHandler and override the default behavior of `do_GET()`.  I am returning a string from my custom handler but the client doesn't receive the response.

Here is my handler class:

```
DUMMY_RESPONSE = """Content-type: text/html

<html>
<head>
<title>Python Test</title>
</head>

<body>
Test page...success.
</body>
</html>
"""

class MyHandler(CGIHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self,req,client_addr,server):
        CGIHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self,req,client_addr,server)

    def do_GET(self):
        return DUMMY_RESPONSE
```

What must I change to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like (untested code):

```
def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
    self.send_header("Content-length", len(DUMMY_RESPONSE))
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(DUMMY_RESPONSE)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!  I also removed the `Content-type` header from my `DUMMY_RESPONSE` string, but otherwise this works as-is.  Great job.

Answer (score 6):

The above answer works but you might get `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` on this line: `self.wfile.write(DUMMY_RESPONSE)`.
You need to do this: `self.wfile.write(str.encode(DUMMY_RESPONSE))`

Comment: You can also set DUMMY_RESPONSE to bytes in python 3, i.e.  `DUMMY_RESPONSE = b"hello there"`

Comment: @Wafula Samuel Would the content-length have to be the length in characters or bytes?